# No logro alinear mis xticklabels con mis xticks...matplotlib python. Que me hace falta?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: grafico de barras error]

No logro alinear mis xticklabels con mis xticks...matplotlib python. Que me hace falta?,
ESTE ES mi CÓDIGO, el que necesito modificar, mis xtickslabels estan 'amontonadas' en la parte inicial del eje 'x', y no logro encontrar que me falta en el codigo para lograr que cada una de ellas se situe justo en el centro de cada grupo de tres barras:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 8))

n = 1  # This is our first dataset (out of 2)
t = 3 # Number of datasets
d = 6 # Number of sets of bars
w = 0.8 # Width of each bar
very = [t*element + w*n for element
             in range(d)]
plt.bar(very, dfsusort['Very interested'], color = '#5cb85c')

n = 2  
t = 3 
d = 6 
w = 0.8 
some = [t*element + w*n for element
             in range(d)]
plt.bar(some, dfsusort['Somewhat interested'], color = '#5bc0de')

n = 3  
t = 3 
d = 6 
w = 0.8 
notin = [t*element + w*n for element
             in range(d)]
plt.bar(notin, dfsusort['Not interested'], color = '#d9534f')

plt.title('Percentage of Respondent`s Interest in Data Science Areas', size=16)
plt.legend(labels=dfsusort.columns, loc='upper right', prop={'size': 14})
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.set_xticks(xticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(dfsusort.index, rotation=90, size=14)
bx = plt.axes()
bx.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
bx.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
bx.spines['left'].set_visible(False)

plt.show
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No muestras como calculas `xticks`, pero son la clave, las etiquetas asignadas con `set_xticklabels` se posicionan en las marcas del eje asignadas con `set_xticks`.

Si quieres que cada etiqueta (índice del DF) aparezca debajo de su grupo de barras, por ejemplo centrada debajo de la barra central, debes usar `some` como marcas mayores para el eje <kbd>X</kbd>:

```
ax.set_xticks(some)
```

Es muy posible que quieras también eliminar las propias marcas de ambos ejes, si es así usa:

```
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', length=0)
```

Con todo el resultado debe ser algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]